# g++ compilation won't end

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I've been trying solve some problem with this code. In my machine, It compiled with no errors with

> g++ "File_name.cpp"

but on the judges machine it uses this command

> g++ -g -O2 -std=gnu++17 -static "File_name.cpp"

and it won't end compiling hence Time limit exceeded. I used the those flags too and it won't finish compiling either.

Anyone Who can help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<utility>
#include<vector>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;

pair<int,int> maxi;
void bfs(vector<vector<char>> &Adj_List, pair<int,int> start);

int main(){
    vector<pair<int,int>> starts;
    cin >> maxi.first >> maxi.second;
    vector<vector<char>> graph(maxi.first);
    char single;
    for(int i = 0; i < maxi.first; i++){ 
        for(int j = 0; j < maxi.second; j++){ 
            cin >> single;
            graph[i].push_back(single);
            if(graph[i][j] == 'V') starts.push_back({i, j});
        }}

    for(auto k:starts) bfs(graph, k);

    for(int i = 0; i < maxi.first; i++){ 
        for(int j = 0; j < maxi.second; j++) cout << graph[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void bfs(vector<vector<char>> &graph, pair<int,int> start){
    queue<pair<int,int>> q;
    q.push({start.first, start.second});
    
    while(!q.empty()){
        pair<int,int> temp = q.front();
        q.pop();
        graph[temp.first][temp.second] = 'V';
        if(temp.first != maxi.first-1) 
            if(graph[temp.first+1][temp.second] != '#') q.push({temp.first+1,temp.second});
        else{ 
            if(temp.second != maxi.second-1 && graph[temp.first][temp.second+1] != '#' && graph[temp.first][temp.second+1] != 'V') 
                q.push({temp.first,temp.second+1});
            if(temp.second != 0 && graph[temp.first][temp.second-1] != '#' && graph[temp.first][temp.second-1] != 'V') 
                q.push({temp.first,temp.second-1});
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Both your compiler and the judges compiler must be broken. My `g++` (`g++ (GCC) 11.2.1 20220127 (Red Hat 11.2.1-9)`) compiles this in 1.2 seconds. Which `g++ --version` do you use?

Comment: Bug: The line `if(temp.first != maxi.first - 1)` and the indentation you use suggests that you think that the following `else` is connected to that line. It's not. The `else` is connected to the `if` just above it. Unlike [tag:python], C++ does not care about indentation. Using the proper indentation for your program reveals what I'm talking about: https://godbolt.org/z/dj17c49n1. You _probably_ mean https://godbolt.org/z/eWKbhMbe9

Comment: I don't think this is a compiler taking a long time to build your code like you suggest. I think its a bug in your algorithm.

Comment: It compiles correctly in my linux machine too.

Comment: Compiles and runs fine for all versions of GCC on godbolt with the given flags. I am voting to close as not reproducible. I suggest OP to add information about the platform and compiler version used. I really doubt though that there happens to be a compiler bug for this code only in a very specific configuration.

Answer (score 0):

as @user17732522 mentioned This problem is not reproducible. because the problem was with the judge side.....rather than uploading the file, copying the code directly to the site fixed the problem.